# can't install ubuntu on xps13

Tags: uefi, disk

I'm trying to install ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell xps13 9350 alongside win10. Once I have prepared a partition in the hard drive, I proceeded with the installation using a bootable usb stick but I can't go beyond the choose og the language, since the laptop can't find enough space to install: basically, it can see only the usb stick available. In there anybody who can help me> Many thanks.

Enrico

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar problem on my Dell XPS13 9360 (The Kaby Lake CPU succeeded the Skylake CPU on the 9350).

A couple of preliminary steps:

1. In the UEFI configuration (Press F2 while booting), disable Secure Boot. Reboot.
2. In Windows 10, Disable Windows Fast Startup. Go into Power Options, select “Choose what the power buttons do”, click on “Change settings that are currently unavailable”, under “Shutdown Settings” uncheck “Turn on fast startup”. Shut down.

Now, RAID is on in by default in the UEFI configuration for the XPS13. Linux, in the case of the XPS13, will not recognize a drive with this setting. The dilemma you face is that Windows 10 is already installed with RAID on, so if you change the setting to allow Linux see the drive, you will not be able to dual boot with Windows 10.

If you want to dual boot, you have two options:

1. Under System Configuration, SATA Operation, change "RAID On" to "AHCI". Boot Linux from your USB stick, partition the drive for both Linux and Windows 10, then install both OSs. You will of course require a copy of Windows 10 as you will lose the installed copy.
2. In Windows 10, shrink the large partition containing the OS so there is room for Linux and a swap partition. Again, change the SATA setting to "ACHI". Boot Linux from the USB stick and install on the remaining space. You will have a dual boot system but will have to change the UEFI configuration for the SATA drive to switch between the two.

If you don't need dual boot, then just change the SATA setting to ACHI and your USB stick will see the drive, which you can then partition as you please.

Comment: How were you able to install 16.04 on your XPS 13 9360? Kaby Lake support is in kernel versions 4.5 and 4.7, but 16.04 has kernel version  4.4. Did it install anyway because Kaby Lake is backwards-compatible with Skylake, and then you updated to a newer kernel?

Comment: And would you mind sharing the level of hardware support for your machine in 16.04? Does everything work out of the box? Any issues?